# How to increase max recursion in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, recursion

When coding a game in unity, I got the error: "StackOverflowException: Max recursion depth of 100 has been exceeded. Consider increasing 'Recursion.defaultMaxDepth'." How do I increase this, or remove it all together?

So I am making an infinite runner game, and have a script that waits for the player to get to a z cord, then put a prefab into the scene. But I am using Unity's Visual Scripting to make it, which with my knowledge, does not have any way to make a function, so all I do it spawn the prefab, I wait for a short time, then check again. But after making 100 prefabs, the script throws the error "StackOverflowException: Max recursion depth of 100 has been exceeded. Consider increasing 'Recursion.defaultMaxDepth'.", and stops. I know making this sort of thing, called a recursion, is bad, but its all I can think of doing, sense I can't make a function. How do I increase this recursion depth, or remove it?

Comment: Whats making it do recursion? You shouldnt need that. Also most endless runners the runners never actually move. Its the scenery. As well as pooling the objects to run on

Comment: An image of your visual script might help. And what does the hierarchy look like when the error occurs? Is it possible you're instantiating new objects as children of the previous one, thus ending up with a very deep ancestry tree?

Comment: @BugFinder I am using a script where the script starts, then doing a wait until, in which it waits for the player to reach a certain point, n which it will spawn a new one. And its not the making of the new prefabs, as its the "Wait until" that is giving the error. Once it loops 100 times, it then gives the error.

Comment: @MilanEgonVotrubec The prefabs no not become children of anything but the scene, and they delete themselves after a set amount of time to preserve memory. And I will add a picture when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue, and the best thing to do is to use the Visual Scripting's functions, which is made by making a custom event, which is just a fancy word for a function. Use this to do actions that are repeated, such as what I was using.